# Linked List Student managment system

Tags: java, linked-list

What the program does: So I have a program that is supposed to give the user 4 options...add student, remove student, print student info, and exit. If the user enters 1 then the add student will be selected and it will ask how many students do you want to add. They will then enter how many they need to add and they will fill out everything needed by the student class for each added. If option 2 is selected then it will remove a student from the linked list by name. If option 3 is selected then it will only print out the students name, zip, and major (the others are to be used in a different project). If option 4 is selected it will exit. It will keep displaying this menu until 4 is selected.

What my issue is: I need help in adding a student to the linked list and removing it by the name of the student. Also 
if someone could explain the toString to me (my teacher told me to do it this way) that would be much appreciated.

Student Class:

```
 public class Student {
private int studentID;
private String fName;
private String lName;
private String Address;
private String city;
private String state;
private String zip;
private String major;


public void Student(){

}

public void Student(int i, String f, String l, String a, String c, String s, String z, String m){
    studentID = i;
    fName = f;
    lName = l;
    Address = a;
    city = c;
    state = s;
    zip = z;
    major = m;
}

public int getStudentID(){
    return studentID;
}
public void setStudentID(int i){
    studentID = i;
}
public String getFName(){
    return fName;
}
public void setFName(String f){
    fName = f;
}
public String getLName(){
    return lName;
}
public void setLName(String l){
    lName = l;
}
public String getAddress(){
    return Address;
}
public void setAddress(String a){
    Address = a;
}
public String getCity(){
    return city;
}
public void setCity(String c){
    city = c;
}
public String getState(){
    return state;
}
public void setState(String s){
    state = s;
}
public String getZip(){
    return zip;
}
public void setZip(String z){
    zip = z;;
}
public String getMajor(){
    return major;
}
public void setMajor(String m){
    major = m;
}

}
```

Linked List Class:

```
public class LinkedList {

private class Node{
    String value;
    Node next;

    Node (String val, Node n){
         value=val;
        next = n;
    }

    Node (String val)
    {
        this(val, null);

    }
}
private Node first;
private Node last;

public LinkedList(){
    first = null;
    last = null;
}

public boolean isEmpty(){
    return first== null;
}

public int size(){
    int count = 0;
    Node p = first;
    while (p !=null){
        count++;
        p = p.next;
    }
    return count;
}

public void add( String s){
    if (isEmpty())
    {
        first = new Node(s);
        last = first;
    }
    else 
    {
        last.next = new Node(s);
        last = last.next;

    }
}

public void  add(int index, String s){
    if (index <0 || index > size()){
        String message = String.valueOf(index);
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(message);
    }


    if (index ==0){
        first = new Node(s, first);
        if (last == null)
            last = first;
        return;
    }

    Node pred = first;
    for (int k = 1; k <= index -1; k++){
        pred = pred.next;
    }
    pred.next = new Node (s, pred.next);

    if (pred.next.next == null){
        last = pred.next;
    }
}
public String toString(){
StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();

Node p = first;
while (p != null){
    strBuilder.append(p.value+"\n");
    p = p.next;

    }
    return strBuilder.toString();
}

public String remove(int index){
    if (index <0 || index >=size()){
        String message = String.valueOf(index);
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(message);
    }

    String element;
    if (index == 0){
        element = first.value;
        first = first.next;
        if (first == null){
            last = null;
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        Node pred = first;
        for (int k = 1; k <=index -1; k++)
            pred = pred.next;


        element = pred.next.value;
        pred.next = pred.next.next;
        if (pred.next ==  null)
            last = pred;

    }
    return element;
}




}
```

Main (which is really bad so far):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class StudentDemo {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner key = new Scanner(System.in);
    LinkedList list = new LinkedList();
    menu();
    int input = key.nextInt();

        if (input == 1){
            if (input ==1){
                System.out.println("Enter name");
                String name = key.nextLine();
                list.add(name);

                System.out.println(list);
            }
        }



}

public static void menu(){
    System.out.println("Student Maintenence System:");
    System.out.println("1. Add Student");
    System.out.println("2. Remove Student");
    System.out.println("3. Print Student Information");
    System.out.println("4. Exit");
}

public static void optionOne(int input, LinkedList list, Scanner key){
    if (input ==1){
        System.out.println("Enter name");/*supposed to ask for a lot more but for the time being its only asking this*/
        String name = key.nextLine();
        list.add(name);
        list.toString();
}
}
}
```

Comment: please do your assignment yourself, first try it by yourself then if you face any problem ask here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my interpretation, it seems that you do not care about the order of students in the linked list. Thus you could have a method for adding such as:

```
// This is the start of your linked list
Node start = ...;

public void add(String s){
    // This may change depending on how you construct a node
    Node toAdd = new Node(s);
    // Iterate until we reach the end
    while(start.getNextNode() != null)
        start = start.getNextNode();
    start.setNextNode(toAdd);

}
```

While you may not have some of the methods I added above, you'd be better off to implement them.

For removing, you could use something like:

```
// This is the start of your linked list
Node start = ...;

public void remove(String s){
    // Iterate until we find the node who's next one is the one to delete
    // We're assuming toString() returns the name of the student
    while(start.getNextNode().toString() != s)
        start = start.getNextNode();
    // Set our next node to the one 2 nodes down the line, thus skipping it
    start.setNextNode(start.getNextNode().getNextNode())

}
```

Now you were asking what a toString method is, and basically a toString() method that returns a string that provides information about an object.
A possible toString() method for the Student class could be

```
public String toString(){
    return "Hello! My name is " + fname + .....; // so on and so on
}
```

Note that **every** object in Java has a toString method, so writing your own will override the method of its super class. If you don't extend a class with a toString(), then it will go all the way back to whichever toString it can find, the furthest of which is the Hex code for its location in memory storage (I may be wrong about this so correct me if it's not)

Hope this helps!